# Server side countdown script

Tags: php, countdown

Time calculations are done on the server side.
It can be created using `JS/jQuery` & `PHP` (or any server side scripting or programming language). Server side script will consider server time and not the local machine time. It will show same remaining time even though you execute it from any geographic location.

Comment: Did you answer your own question? Or is your question how to change the code in your answer or what is this all about?

Answer (score 0):

JS Code:

```html
<script>
 jQuery(document).ready(function() {   
   var refreshId_sec = setInterval(function() {   
      var target_url = 'show_diff.php?show=all&randval='+ Math.random();      
   jQuery.ajax({url: target_url, success: function(result){
  var arr_res = result.split("|");  
  document.getElementById('sec').innerHTML = arr_res[3];
  document.getElementById('min').innerHTML = arr_res[2];
  document.getElementById('hour').innerHTML = arr_res[1];
  document.getElementById('day').innerHTML = arr_res[0];
    }});
   }, 1000);
</script>
```

PHP Code:

```html
<?php

$then = '2016-04-08 10:00:00'; // end time here
$then = new DateTime($then, new DateTimeZone('Asia/Calcutta'));
$now = new DateTime();
$sinceThen = $then->diff($now);
if($_GET["show"]=="all")
 echo $sinceThen->d."|".$sinceThen->h."|".$sinceThen->i."|".$sinceThen->s;
?>
```

Check full code on: http://blog.phpcode.co.in/php/server-side-countdown-counter-script/